# What is equivalent of the Nz Function in MS Access in MySQL? Is Nz a SQL standard?

Tags: sql, mysql, database, ms-access

What is MySQL equivalent of the `Nz` Function in Microsoft Access? Is `Nz` a SQL standard?

In Access, the `Nz` function lets you return a value when a variant is null. [Source](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/nz.php)

The syntax for the `Nz` function is:

```
Nz ( variant, [ value_if_null ] )
```

Comment: It is **[`IFNULL ( expression, value_if_null )`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-functions.html#function_ifnull)**.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [`COALESCE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function does what you describe.  It's standard SQL and it should be supported in all SQL databases.

The [`IFNULL()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-functions.html#function_ifnull) function is not standard SQL.  Only some brands of databases support this function.

Answer (score 4):

COALESCE does just what the OP is asking for, as does IFNULL:

```
SELECT Nz(MightBeNullVar, 0) FROM ...  (MS Access version)
SELECT COALESCE(MightBeNullVar, 0) FROM ... (MySQL version)
SELECT IFNULL(MightBeNullVar, 0) FROM ... (MySQL version)
```

The difference is the COALESCE can search through multiple variables and return the first non-null one:

```
SELECT COALESCE(MightBeNullVar, MightAlsoBeNullVar, CouldBeNullVar, 0) FROM ... (MySQL version)
```

each of these will return a 0 (zero) if none of the values have a set value (are null).

The IFNULL is (pretty meaninglessly) faster.  There's probably other better things to optimize in your query before bothering with IFNULL vs COALESCE issues.  If you have multiple things to check, use COALESCE.  If you only have a single value to check, use IFNULL.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look at `IFNULL` or `COALESCE`. If I recall correctly, `IFNULL` works for MySQL.

Comment: IFNULL is the equivalent for mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Have look to the null safe operator <=>

Maybe it could help :
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps Knowing what MS Access NZ() Function actually does would be helpful (prior to answering with completely invalid suggestions). The NZ() Function test for Null and Replaces the Null with an empty string, a Zero or optionally a value that the user enters.

COALESCE doesn't even come close, in fact it returns a Null if no none Null values in a 'List???'

IFNULL() Function is what you're looking for.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/control-flow-functions.html

Comment: The idea with COALESCE is that you make the last value your default non-null value:  COALESCE(MightBeNull, MightAlsoBeNull, CouldBeNull, 'DefaultValue') ...

Comment: Here here, right on!  And might I add, that nz() doesn't require a list at all.  It can work on a single element to get rid of any nulls in it, and return zero or "".  It's a great tool to deal with nulls.  Coalesce doesn't do the same thing, and on top of that if used with 2 parameters is frankly wordy and clunky.  i.e. you can't Coalesce(x).  But you can nz(x).